What are these 1 day old accounts?
For some time already, I see on old questions of mine answers that make more or less sense, from 1/a few days old accounts with (obviously) a very low rep (example for a 7 years old question).
Has this been analyzed (at the level of SO) and are there any conclusions?
These may be bots (but then why the recent upsurge?)? Or bots coupled with an AI to guess a response that makes more or less sense (say, it is in the area of the question)?
What is their use? (not spamming as it used to be the case before)

I think it is a new user just trying to help someone but they are not aware of our high-quality answer standards

The answers will likely appear in the First answers queue and provided they aren't seen by an auto-reviewer, should get handled by that.

@Anonymous still, I see a rise of such answers for the last, what 2  years maybe and never had it before (I have been on SO for 13-14 years). But maybe this is just a feeling.

Might be related to the sign-up flow changes. They've added Google one-tap resulting in more users which might result in posts from these new users as well.

There could be a bit of a "Baader Meinhof phenomenon" in play here, where you notice something more often, after attention was drawn to something initially.

@Cerbrus yes, this is what I had in mind in the previous comment.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I don't think so it's related to the signups. The example given is just a normal unregistered account.

@VLAZ the example is probably just a person happening on the question and deciding to post an answer. The question talks about an upsurge of answers posted by new accounts which might be related to creation of new accounts becoming easier.

It is a way to avoid the attention associated with new questions (and thus immediate downvotes, and, ultimately, the associated ban). They can then hope for an occasional random upvote. It is almost always minimum effort, and a spot check will often reveal an answer to be complete bogus and/or the result of plagiarism (ChatGPT or old-school plagiarism, in both cases blinding copying from some page on the Internet without any understanding of what they are posting).
